# Problem Merge Audio To Video on iPhone 5s

Tags: ios, swift, video, merge

I Merge Audio File To Video, That's works well on Other devices but except iPhone 5s,5. The error is :

> Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11822 "Cannot Open" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=This media format is not supported., NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot Open, NSUnderlyingError=0x600003c0a2e0 {Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-16976 "(null)"}}

video file is **mp4** type and resolution is **1920*1080**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Transferring and playing MP4 on iPhone 5S is usually smooth for many users. However, due to the codec, video size and resolution issue, you may have difficulty in playing MP4 on iPhone 5S or 5C. You may encounter the following symptoms when trying to play MP4 on iPhone 5S:

- MP4 files cannot be added to iTunes thus cannot be transferred to iPhone 5S for play.
- MP4 files can be added to iTunes but when syncing with your iPhone 5S, iTunes pops up a message: “movie was not copied to the iPhone 5S because it cannot be played on this iPhone 5S”.
- iPhone 5S MP4 no audio: No audio or sound when you play MP4 on iPhone 5S
- iPhone 5S MP4 no video: No video or image when you play MP4 on iPhone 5S
- iPhone 5S cannot read and play some MP4 file

In order to successfully play MP4 files on iPhone 5S, MP4 files shall meet the following requirements:

- H.264 video up to 720p, 30 frames per second, Main Profile level 3.1 with AAC-LC audio up to 160 Kbps, 48kHz, stereo audio;
- MPEG-4 video, up to 2.5 Mbps, 640 by 480 pixels, 30 frames per second, Simple Profile with AAC-LC audio up to 160 Kbps, 48kHz, stereo audio.

Your iPhone 5S will not recognize the MP4 files if they don’t match the above requirements.